# zsh completion difference

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I have seen many do this
`autoload -Uz compinit

compinit`
and others do this
`autoload -U compinit

compinit -i`
I would like to know the difference. which one should I use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`autoload`, from [`man zshbuiltins`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins):

> The flags `-z` and `-k` mark the function to be autoloaded in native or ksh  emulation,  as  if the option `KSH_AUTOLOAD` were unset or were set, respectively.

The `-U` flag can be traced back: `autoload` is equivalent to `function -u`, which is equivalent to `typeset -f`. `typeset`, in a nutshell, is used to:

> Set or display attributes and values for shell parameters.

When `-f` is used in combination with `-U`:

> [The -f flag causes] The  names  refer to functions rather than parameters. ... The -u and -U flags cause the function to be marked for autoloading; -U also causes alias expansion to be suppressed when the function is loaded.

`compinit` is the completion initialization function used by `compsys`, the 'newer' Z-Shell completion system. See [`man zshcompsys`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshcompsys) for details.

The `-i` flag is used to:

> to make compinit silently ignore all insecure files and directories use the option -i

In general, you should be using `autoload -Uz`, according to [this interesting read](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2012/003/).

Comment: *"-Uz"? Yes, that is "the right thing"[tm] almost always, so I won't discuss it here* - meh, the one part i was looking for isn't actually explained in the article

Comment: I haven't found further sources for `-Uz`, but my own interpretation of the man page is that `-z` marks autoloading via `zsh` (ie, 'native'), which is ideal because you're running zsh. `-U` prevents alias expansion, which is (presumably) good when loading functions because you may have alises that override function names, and the order of loading (alias, function vs function, alias) might break things.